# Apparent weight on a hill and in a ditch

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, weight

first time posting.

I'm trying to solve these 2 problems. I have a solutions I just don't know if I'm right...seems odd that they are the same answer...

> 1) If you are driving over a hill of radius of curvature **r**. How fast must you drive for you to lift up off your chair.

**My solution**: Since at that point **Fn** is 0, then **Fnet = Fc = mg** so we have **mv^2/r = mg** which rearranges to give you a required speed of **v=sqrt(gr)**

...this is fine, it makes sense to me. It's the fact that I got the same answer for the next one that is throwing me off

> 2) If you are driving your car into a dip in the road of curvature **r**. How fast must you drive for you to feel twice as heavy.

**My solution**: ok so here I figured **|Fn| = 2mg** since it's normally **mg** so then I have this...
**Fnet = Fc = Fn - Fg**  .... **mv^2/r = 2mg - mg = mg** so again I get **v=sqrt(gr)**

Like...it seems right to me...?

Comment: Hi SGBurek, and welcome to Physics Stackexchange. As it stands, this will probably be closed because we have a rather strict [homework/homework-like policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) - In particular, even if you show your work, we aren't here to check that work for you. It's better to phrase questions conceptually - *why* does this seem a contradiction? what other behavior would you expect? etc.

Answer (score 1):

Both of them are correct. If you have a velocity such that at the top of the hill you feel no weight, when you are in the dip you'll feel twice your weight (at same curvature radius r).